# Magento reindexing

Tags: magento2, indexing

i had install Magento 2 (php 7.0.x), but it showing me error message

> ** System messages
>
> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
>   running.
>   **

as per suggestion on forums i also fire query

`php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex`

but it showing me error on console:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in E:\wamp\www\Magentosample\vendor\ma
>   gento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 93

i am not getting the issue.

i had also add some product (**status = Enabled**) but the product are not visible on customer view.

Please help me to solve both the issues.

Comment: Have you remove var folder from root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reindex in Magento 2, go to root directory of Magento using cli and run this command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Magento 2 relies on cron jobs to be ran every minute. First open up crontab for username that has write permissions for magento root folder (suppose it is _www (on mac osx it is), basically it is the user your php-fpm or httpd running under):

   ```
   crontab -u _www -e
   ```

   then add the following lines there:

   ```
   * * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path_to_magento_root/bin/magento setup:cron:run
   * * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path_to_magento_root/bin/magento cron:run
   * * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path_to_magento_root/update/cron.php
   ```

   make sure you put the correct path to php executable, check it with:

   ```
   which php
   ```
2. check *vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php* for syntax errors:

   ```
   php -l vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
   ```

   looks like you have one at line 93. (did you edit this file?)

Comment: @Gerasimov no, i have not

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you edit file E:\wamp\www\Magentosample\vendor\ma gento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php. And it have  syntax error... so try revert all changes, for example by remove vendor folder and run composer install